# Find $f(x,y,z) = 0$ that excludes $q$ and $v$ parameters

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry, parametric

I have the following problem: 
$$x = e^q \sin (q) + v$$
$$y = e^q\cos (q) + 2v$$
$$z = e^q + 3v$$
I want to find a function $$f(x, y, z) = 0$$, that is i want to remove the $q$ and $v$ parameters from the equation.
How can I do it ?
Here is my attempt: $$ (x-v)^2 + (y -2v)^2 = e^{2q}$$
$$ (z-3v)^2 = e^{2q}$$
from which I get:
$$x^2 + y^2  - 2vx -4vy = z^2 -6vz + 4v^2$$
Now $q$ is excluded but i don't know how to exclude $v$ too.

Comment: My pedantic nature absolutely insists I point out the constant function $f \equiv 0$. I assume you're not looking for this function?

Comment: this is in the context of equation of cylinder, so I assume no.

Comment: @Anonymous Then you should state that you are looking for a function $f$ such that $f(x, y, z) = 0$ iff there exist $q, v$ such that $(x,y,z)$ is given by the equations above.

Comment: The last equation is already a quadratic equation in $v$.
Solve it and you'll get $v$ in terms of $x,y,z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $$v(x,y,z)=3z-x-2y\pm \sqrt{(3z-x-2y)^2-z^2+x^2+y^2}.$$
and $$q(x,y,z)=\arctan \frac{x-v}{y-2v}+\pi k,$$ so
$$f(x,y,z)=e^{q(x,y,z)}+3v(x,y,z)-z=0.$$